# Electric field in a sphere embedded in a medium

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

Consider a system where a sphere of conductivity $\sigma_i$ is embedded in a large medium of conductivity $\sigma_e$. An electric field $E_0$ is applied and the question is, what is the electric field $E_{int}$ inside the sphere?

The answer given by https://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~stroud/stroud1.pdf file in equation (1) is

$E_{int} = E_0\frac{3\sigma_e}{\sigma_i+2\sigma_e}$

and the author claims this is an elementary result from electrostatics. Can anyone help me understand how this comes about?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields

Comment: Not sure how to connect the conductivities of the media with the bound/surface charge. Could you elaborate?